# When updating a Chrome window, what does "drawAttention" actually do?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The [chrome.windows.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update) method lets you update a window like this:

```
chrome.windows.update(windowId, {
  drawAttention: true
});
```

The docs say this about the `drawAttention` option:

> If true, causes the window to be displayed in a manner that draws the user's attention to the window, without changing the focused window. The effect lasts until the user changes focus to the window. This option has no effect if the window already has focus. Set to false to cancel a previous draw attention request.

What does that mean in practice? I can't see any effect on OS X. Does it do something on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a Windows or Linux system, it'll cause the taskbar button for that window to start flashing.

There's no standard way for a window to request attention on Mac OS X (bouncing the Dock icon applies to applications, not windows), so that option isn't implemented there.